# Can I add rich formatting (bold, italics, underline) on XForms labels and hints?

Tags: format, xforms, text-formatting, odk, javarosa

We are developing an XForms-based survey system. The client wants to add rich-formatting to labels and hints.

Is this possible? If so, how do you define formatting on the XForm xml? Is there a reference page that I can go to?

UPDATE: We're currently implementing for ODK, which uses JavaRosa. We're planning to launch our own mobile application later, keeping compatibility with the current ODK Collect application.

UPDATE 2: Our client would actually like to have a label in the form of:

> The *quick* **brown** fox jumped over the ***lazy*** dog.

Comment: Which XForms engine are you planning to use? I suppose that your question aims at an implementation-specific issue. If you're using a server-side solution, it's likely that you can use standard CSS to style the labels and hints.

Comment: @tohuwawohu right, I forgot. We're currently using ODK Collect as client (which uses JavaRosa). We plan to develop our own compatible HTML5 client on the future.

Comment: This seems to be an ODK limitation because other XForms implementations (such as mine, XSLTForms) allow html elements with styling for labels or hints.

Comment: @PabloVenturino: sorry, i don't have any experience with ODK Collect, so i can't help you with this. As Alain states, it seems to be a limitation of that software. Most server-side frameworks allow for displaying arbitrary HTML content in labels and hints.

Comment: @PabloVenturino As Alain said, it definitely depends on the implementation. XForms itself allows rich (inline) formatting within labels, help, hint and alert elements.

Comment: Thanks guys, I get it. <label> and <hint> elements support html inside them, but our current client does not support it. We'll assume this as the correct way of formatting when we implement our client. Can you guys say this as an answer, so I can upvote and accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ODK Collect doesn't have rich formatting but [you can use images](http://opendatakit.org/help/image-based-forms/). I put together [a text renderer](http://bit.ly/Nx17yR) that allows you to format your text with pango markup if that's any help.